# Getting the correct scala actor sender reference when sending from an different class

Tags: scala, actor

Within my actor I have to create a class which sends a message to another actor. The other actor should reply back to actor A

```
class A extends Actor {

val b = new B
b.start

val i = new DefaultHandler() {
            override def fun(a: String) = {  
                b ! payload
            }
        }
someotherclass.registerHandler(i)

def act = {
      loop {
        react {
          case reply => //do something

}

class B extends Actor {

def act = {
      loop {
        react {
          case msg => sender ! reply

          }
}
```

The problem now is that while sending from the inner class I'm not within the actor itself anymore and as a result actor B does not get a correct reference to actor B. One way to fix this would be to pass a reference to A via the message but this seems quite ugly to me.

```
val ref = self
val i = new DefaultClass() {
            override def fun(a: String) = {  
                b ! message(payload, ref)
            }
        }
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actor B receives the correct reference, which is not A. However you already answered your own question.

A different approach would include:

1. Extending from Actor
2. Optional: Have an implicit conversion to your kind of Actor
3. Have an implicit actor reference in your message operator

In that case your DefaultHandler would have to keep a reference to your original Actor as well.